# Mercurial - How to specify branch on commit?

Tags: mercurial, branch, commit

I would like, when a user commit a changeset, to show a message mentioning the branch where the changeset was committed.

Example:

```
$hg commit -m 'Fix bug'
Changeset committed on branch bugfix
```

Do I actually need to modify the hg commit code or is it a quicker/simpler way of doing it?

Comment: It's worth noting that if you don't use `-m` to short cut the comment that the branch is displayed.  I know it takes a second longer but I avoid using `-m` exactly because I want to see the list of "what will be committed and where will it go" that shows up in the comment block of the comment editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to your repository's .hg/hgrc:

```
[hooks]
commit=echo "Changeset committed on branch `hg branch`"
```

Answer (score 5):

ssg's answer is unfortunately not portable to e.g. Windows (because of the backticks), but this should work:

```
# UNIX-like
[hooks]
commit=hg log -r $HG_NODE --template "Committing on branch {branch}\n"
```

or

```
# Windows
[hooks]
commit=hg log -r %HG_NODE% --template "Committing on branch {branch}\n"
```

Comment: @ssg Fair enough :-) I didn't notice that.